# Space complexity when hashmap is used as a counter

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

Come across code like this:

```
void foo(const string& str) {
  unordered_map<char, unsigned int> m;
  for (char c: str) {
    ++m[c];
  }
}
```

What's the space complexity?
if the answer is O(1), then what if the algorithm is to count the unique occurrence of 8-byte stream (or 16-byte 32-bye etc)? i.e. the upper bound of the problem space out sizes the memory space of a computer.

Answer (score 1):

The space complexity of your problem in O(length(str)).

As for the string, you are creating a new entry per new charachter met.

Now there are few things to be considered in your case :
Is length of string greater than that of total charachter set defined by char data type.

If yes then space complexity is of O(total chars in char datatype) = O(1)
else it is O(length(str)).

Same goes for utf-32 char type.

Now it completely depends on what your inputs are -
If the inputs are of huge sizes, commonly greater than total size of char datatype or utf-32 size, the space complexity be considered as constant.

Comment: Pls explain. There's an upper limit right? length of the string can be a billion, but there'll only be maximum 256 (size of char) elements in the hash map. The space used is not linear to the length of string.

Answer (score 1):

2,164,864 “characters” can be potentially coded by UTF-8.

So, if all the characters are present in a given string then the number of bytes used is 2,164,864 bytes (Supposing 1 byte per character).

As... 2,164,864 is also a constant. So in any case space complexity of the problem remains O(1).

***O(1) signifies constant space.***

Comment: If you monitor the memory space the hashmap used, it'll grow based on the number of unique characters in the input string. Can you call this 'constant space'?

Comment: But at most how much it will reach... its upper bound is O(1).

Comment: what if the algorithm is to count the unique occurrence of 8-byte stream (or 16-byte 32-bye etc)? i.e. the upper bound of the problem space out sizes the memory space of a computer. Is it still counted as 'constant space'?

Comment: Actually I am considering character as 1 byte only... Then I think it will be better to consider it as O(n).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does that number come from? There are just 1,114,112 Unicode code points (17 planes of 65536 codepoints each). 2048 of those are surrogates, which cannot be represented in valid UTF-8, so if you restrict to valid UTF-8 codeppintss, there are 1,112,064 of them. A few of those are permanently non-characters, but they can still be transmitted.